# How to increase fast-forward/rewind on Vista Media Center recorded TV shows?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-center, recording, tv, dvr

How do I granularly increase the various fast-forward/rewind speed/rate for each of the speed settings for skipping through commercials?

The current defaults go from barely faster than playback, too fast for unexpectedly short commercials, to omfg its so fast I can't see what is happening.

Do people suffer with these defaults, or is there some better setting in the registry, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's certainly a 30 second skip on both Vista Media Center and Windows 7 Media Center -- I use it every day to skip commercials!

Just press the chapter forward key during playback and that will skip 30 sec.

Comment: Hmm, my Harmony 659 doesn't have specific chapter skip button, just the fast forward/rewind. Will have to see if I can decipher the names of the commands to buttons.

Comment: Found "SkipScene" and "BackScene" in the button assignments, so I added those to the activity section, since everything else on the remote was already assigned to something more important. Thanks :)